# Get entities belonging to a given account in Android Room

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, android-room

I need to get a list of favorite movies for a specific account, now I have a common database of favorite movies for all accounts. I have no idea how to write SQL query in this situtaion

account entity

```
@Entity(tableName = "account_table")
data class AccountEntity(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val userId: Int,
    val firstName: String,
    val login: String,
    val password: String,
)
```

Seelected movies entity

```
@Entity(tableName = "selected_movies_table")
data class SelectedMoviesEntity(
    @PrimaryKey val id: String,
    val title: String,
    val image: String
)
```

I have tried a JOIN and a relation annotation but probaby something goes wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have a relationship between the user and the movies associated with the user. The 2 entities (tables) you have show have no such relationship between the two.

There are 3 types of relationship

1. a 1-1, that is a user can have 1 related movie (since you mention favourite movies i.e. plural) then this type of relationship will not suit.
2. a 1-many, relationship where where a user can have many related movies but the movie can only be related to a single user. In this type of relationship the many (the movies) would include a field that references the 1 user. If this type were used, then a movie could only be a favourite for a single user. This is probably not what you want.
3. The last type is a many-many relationship where a a user can have many related movies AND a movies can be related to many users. Such a relationship uses an 3rd table that has two columns, one to reference the user, the other to reference the movie. The primary key would be comprised of both columns. **This is probably the most suitable relationship.**

Assuming the many-many relationship then you need a 3rd table, the following could be used:-

```
@Entity(
    primaryKeys = ["userIdMap","movieIdMap"],
    /*Optional but suggested - enforces Referential Integrity*/
    foreignKeys = [
        ForeignKey(
            entity = AccountEntity::class,
            parentColumns = ["userId"],
            childColumns = ["userIdMap"],
            /* Optional within Foreign Key helps to maintain Referential Integirty*/
            onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE,
            onUpdate = ForeignKey.CASCADE
        ),
        ForeignKey(
            entity = SelectedMoviesEntity::class,
            parentColumns = ["id"],
            childColumns = ["movieIdMap"],
            onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE,
            onUpdate = ForeignKey.CASCADE
        )
    ]
)
data class FavouriteMoviesMappingEntity(
    val userIdMap: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(index = true)
    val movieIdMap: String
)
```

Obviously you need to be able to insert FavouriteMoviesMappingEntity rows (see allDAOs later).

**However** to be able to retrieve a User with their Favourite Movies you need an object that Room can return from queries. That Object should include the parent **AccountEntity** and a list of **SelectedMoviesEntities** for the related movies.

The  **AccountEntity** being just the single occurrence can be `@Embedded`. The list of **SelectedMoviesEntities* being a relationship can use the `@Relation` annotation.

As the relationship is a many-many relationship then the 3rd table needs to be specified (such a table has many names such as associative table, reference table mapping table ....). What relates to what also needs to be specified.

For this *special* object you use a POJO such as:-

```
data class UserWithFavouriteMovies(
    @Embedded
    val accountEntity: AccountEntity,
    @Relation(
        entity = SelectedMoviesEntity::class,
        parentColumn = "userId",
        entityColumn = "id",
        associateBy = Junction(
            value = FavouriteMoviesMappingEntity::class,
            parentColumn = "userIdMap",
            entityColumn = "movieIdMap"
        )
    )
    val favouriteMovies: List<SelectedMoviesEntity>
)
```

To get a user (AccountEntity) with the FavouriteMovies you simply need an `@Query` annotated function, where the query that extracts the respective user(s) and the function returns a list of the POJO (UserWithFavouriteMovies) objects.

**Demonstration**

Using the @Entity annotated classes from the question and the above classes and then:-

The following `@Dao` annotated interface:-

```
@Dao
interface AllDAOs {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    fun insert(accountEntity: AccountEntity): Long
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    fun insert(selectedMoviesEntity: SelectedMoviesEntity): Long
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    fun insert(favouriteMoviesMappingEntity: FavouriteMoviesMappingEntity): Long

    @Transaction
    @Query("SELECT * FROM account_table")
    fun getUserWithFavouriteMovies(): List<UserWithFavouriteMovies>
}
```

A suitable `@Database` annotated abstract class such as:-

```
@Database(entities = [AccountEntity::class,SelectedMoviesEntity::class, FavouriteMoviesMappingEntity::class], exportSchema = false, version = 1)
abstract class TheDatabase: RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun getAllDAOs(): AllDAOs

    companion object {
        private var instance: TheDatabase?=null
        fun getInstance(context: Context): TheDatabase {
            if (instance==null) {
                instance = Room.databaseBuilder(context,TheDatabase::class.java,"the_database.db")
                    .allowMainThreadQueries() /* For brevity of the demo */
                    .build()
            }
            return instance as TheDatabase
        }
    }
}
```

and finally some activity code to demonstrate:-

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var db: TheDatabase
    lateinit var dao: AllDAOs
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        db = TheDatabase.getInstance(this)
        dao = db.getAllDAOs()

        val fredId = dao.insert(AccountEntity(0,"Fred","fredlogin","fredpassword"))
        val janeId = dao.insert(AccountEntity(0,"Jane","janelogin","janepassword"))
        val maryid = dao.insert(AccountEntity(0,"Mary","marylogin","marypassword"))
        val tomId = dao.insert(AccountEntity(0,"Tom","tomlogin","tompassword"))

        dao.insert(SelectedMoviesEntity("Movie1","Movie 1 Title","Movie1Image"))
        dao.insert(SelectedMoviesEntity("Movie2","Movie 2 Title","Movie2Image"))
        dao.insert(SelectedMoviesEntity("Movie3","Movie 3 Title","Movie3Image"))
        dao.insert(SelectedMoviesEntity("Movie4","Movie 4 Title","Movie4Image"))
        dao.insert(SelectedMoviesEntity("Movie5","Movie 5 Title","Movie5Image"))
        dao.insert(SelectedMoviesEntity("Movie6","Movie 6 Title","Movie6Image"))
        dao.insert(SelectedMoviesEntity("Movie7","Movie 7 Title","Movie7Image"))

        dao.insert(FavouriteMoviesMappingEntity(userIdMap = fredId.toInt(), movieIdMap = "Movie3"))
        dao.insert(FavouriteMoviesMappingEntity(userIdMap = fredId.toInt(), movieIdMap = "Movie1"))
        dao.insert(FavouriteMoviesMappingEntity(userIdMap = fredId.toInt(), movieIdMap = "Movie5"))
        dao.insert(FavouriteMoviesMappingEntity(userIdMap = janeId.toInt(), movieIdMap = "Movie2"))
        dao.insert(FavouriteMoviesMappingEntity(userIdMap = janeId.toInt(), movieIdMap = "Movie4"))
        dao.insert(FavouriteMoviesMappingEntity(userIdMap = janeId.toInt(), movieIdMap = "Movie6"))

        dao.insert(FavouriteMoviesMappingEntity(userIdMap = maryid.toInt(), movieIdMap = "Movie3"))
        dao.insert(FavouriteMoviesMappingEntity(userIdMap = maryid.toInt(), movieIdMap = "Movie1"))
        dao.insert(FavouriteMoviesMappingEntity(userIdMap = maryid.toInt(), movieIdMap = "Movie5"))
        dao.insert(FavouriteMoviesMappingEntity(userIdMap = maryid.toInt(), movieIdMap = "Movie2"))
        dao.insert(FavouriteMoviesMappingEntity(userIdMap = maryid.toInt(), movieIdMap = "Movie4"))
        dao.insert(FavouriteMoviesMappingEntity(userIdMap = maryid.toInt(), movieIdMap = "Movie6"))

        for (uwfm in dao.getUserWithFavouriteMovies()) {
            val sb = StringBuilder()
            for (fm in uwfm.favouriteMovies) {
                sb.append("\n\tMovie Title is ${fm.title} Image is ${fm.image}")
            }
            Log.d("DBINFO","User is ${uwfm.accountEntity.firstName} etc, user has ${uwfm.favouriteMovies.size} Favourites. They are:-${sb}")
        }
    }
}
```

The the result output to the log is:-

```
2023-05-02 06:50:25.781 D/DBINFO: User is Fred etc, user has 3 Favourites. They are:-
        Movie Title is Movie 1 Title Image is Movie1Image
        Movie Title is Movie 3 Title Image is Movie3Image
        Movie Title is Movie 5 Title Image is Movie5Image
        
2023-05-02 06:50:25.781 D/DBINFO: User is Jane etc, user has 3 Favourites. They are:-
        Movie Title is Movie 2 Title Image is Movie2Image
        Movie Title is Movie 4 Title Image is Movie4Image
        Movie Title is Movie 6 Title Image is Movie6Image
        
2023-05-02 06:50:25.781 D/DBINFO: User is Mary etc, user has 6 Favourites. They are:-
        Movie Title is Movie 1 Title Image is Movie1Image
        Movie Title is Movie 2 Title Image is Movie2Image
        Movie Title is Movie 3 Title Image is Movie3Image
        Movie Title is Movie 4 Title Image is Movie4Image
        Movie Title is Movie 5 Title Image is Movie5Image
        Movie Title is Movie 6 Title Image is Movie6Image
        
2023-05-02 06:50:25.781 D/DBINFO: User is Tom etc, user has 0 Favourites. They are:-
```

That is, as expected Fred has 3 favourites, Jane also has 3 favourites but they are different to Fred's. Mary has 6 favourites 3 the same as Fred and the other 3 the same as Jane. Tom has no favourites. Not shown, but Movie 7 does is not a favourite of any.